# Is Docker For Mac same as Docker Community Edition (Mac OS High Sierra)

Tags: macos, docker, macos-highsierra

I am using Docker CE v18.06.0-ce-mac70 (26399). Is Docker For Mac same as Docker Community Edition (Mac OS High Sierra)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, “Docker CE (Community Edition)” is the same as “Docker Desktop” and yes, this all sounds confusing. But [the download page makes it somewhat clearer](https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac):

> Docker CE for Mac is an easy-to-install desktop app for building, debugging, and testing Dockerized apps on a Mac. Docker for Mac is a complete development environment deeply integrated with the Mac OS Hypervisor framework, networking, and filesystem. Docker for Mac is the fastest and most reliable way to run Docker on a Mac.

The naming is horrible to be honest. There is also “Docker Toolbox” which is not a packaged Mac app but rather is a pure command line tool that—I believe—predates Docker Desktop [as explained here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/):

> Docker Toolbox installs `docker`, `docker-compose`, and `docker-machine` in `/usr/local/bin` on your Mac. It also installs VirtualBox. At installation time, Toolbox uses `docker-machine` to provision a VirtualBox VM called `default`, running the `boot2docker` Linux distribution, with Docker Engine with certificates located on your Mac at `$HOME/.docker/machine/machines/default`.

The concussion also seems to come from the fact that there is a “Docker EE (Enterprise Edition)” that is basically like the CE (Community Edition) but is a “Containers-as-a-Service” setup.

Honestly, answering this question has made me less confused about Docker options for Mac, but honestly more dizzy and—possibly—confused in new ways.

If you have to ask, then I will assume “Docker Desktop” (aka: Community Edition)‚ is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is Docker For Mac same as Docker Community Edition (Mac OS High Sierra)?

According to the release notes, yes.

> **Docker for Mac Stable release notes**
>
> Here are the main improvements and issues per stable release, starting
>   with the current release. The documentation is updated for each
>   release.
>
> ...
>
> **Stable Releases of 2018**
>
> Docker Community Edition 18.06.0-ce-mac70 2018-07-25

Source [Docker for Mac Stable release notes | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/)